# Unable to uninstall fedora 24 and install Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, fedora

I have fedora 24 on my laptop. I want to delete fedora and install ubuntu 14.04 (yes old version). I made ubuntu live usb using unetbootin in fedora and when I try to boot from usb, fedora boots automatically. Unable to boot ubuntu from usb. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want make ubuntu 14.04 your primary OS for your laptop then do the following steps:

1. Download the ubuntu 14.04 iso file.
2. Download and install PowerISO on your System.
3. Install the iso in your Pendrive using powerISO  using terminal command wget or download physically and un-tar it. http://www.poweriso.com/poweriso-1.3.tar.gz
4. open powerISO and click on tool tab,the select Bootable usb.
5. Burn dialog box will open, choose the un-tar iso file and click on start button.
   viola you are half way done.
6. Now restart your os and boot your lappy to read usb storage first.
7. Follow the instruction and your ubuntu will be installed..

Note: you can also install the powerISO package from [here](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AKenzy%3Apackages&package=poweriso)